# How come January doesn't have an 'r' in the name like February?

Tags: names, reason-why

What is the reason for why February has an 'r' after the 'b' but January doesn't have an 'r' after the 'n'? Like so: Janruary, February. There must be an explanation for this, historical or otherwise.

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Roman calendar *January* was the month of *Janus*, the god of gates and doorways (*janua*), this month being the "doorway" to the year. *February* was the month of purificatory rites, *februa*.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the history:

http://www.crowl.org/Lawrence/time/months.html

A History of the Months
January -- **Janus**'s month

February -- month of **Februa**

The original LATIN word from which they were created show this.